# In C++, how to write a function so that it can work on any data type?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I am learning C++ STL using this resource : http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=standardTemplateLibrary

The following function to reverse elemens of an array is given there :

```
template<typename T> void reversearr(T *begin, T *end) { 
      // We should at first decrement 'end' 
      // But only for non-empty range 
      if(begin != end) 
      { 
           end--; 
           if(begin != end) { 
                while(true) { 
                     swap(*begin, *end); 
                     begin++; 
                     if(begin == end) { 
                          break; 
                     } 
                     end--; 
                     if(begin == end) { 
                          break; 
                     } 
                } 
           } 
      } 
 }
```

It works on system-defined types arrays such as:

```
int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5}
reversearr(arr,arr+5);
```

But it gives the following compiler error:

"Iterator02_ReverseIterators.cpp:39:32: error: no matching function for call to 'reversearr(std::vector::iterator, std::vector::iterator)'"

if I use this code:

```
vector<int> v;
//Code to insert data in vector
reversearr(v.begin(),v.end());
```

How to write the similar functions so that they can work on iterators too?

Comment: "But it gives compiler error" what is the error?

Comment: The STL model is to use ["iterators"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator). These abstract the idea of a pointer, so you can typically increment them, dereference them, etc. Look at the functions in the [`<algorithm>` header](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm). For something simple like [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) you can see how it might work on all kinds of container. (I won't make this an answer, since your best bet is to read material from various other parts of the internet.)

Comment: Sorry, edited to include the error

Comment: the `T*` is more than likely the culprit.

Comment: Working on _any_ data type will be a challenge. Reversing a single-linked list is _not_ easy as you're missing `--` and can only use `++`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, the parameter is the pointer of `T`. When you use an iterator, the parameter is the pointer to an iterator, so it doesn't work.

If you want it to work with iterators, I think you should write like this:

```
template<typename T> 
void reversearr(T begin, T end)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Oh I didn't realise it was this simple! :P Thanks @wangxf :)

Comment: Just for reference, though, don't use a name like `T`.  :)  Pick a name that says "hey, i'm an iterator of some sort".

Comment: @cHao, Agreed! :) But I used 'T' because I'm just learning the concept and not actually developing something :)

Comment: @user2916888: naming does not come after the fact, but better *before* it. If you named the type 'Iterator', then it would have been almost obvious that 'Iterator*' is not the type of the argument.  Naming will help you understand your code and getting from intent to implementation more often than not.

Comment: @David Rodriguez, I agree, but you see, it not even my own code. I've taken it directly from the source I'm learning from. (Topcoder)

Answer (score 7):

Welp, cppreference.com again has a full answer for us, also known as [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse):

Possible implementation:

```
template<class BidirIt>
void reverse(BidirIt first, BidirIt last)
{
    while ((first != last) && (first != --last)) {
        std::iter_swap(first++, last);
    }
}
```

Where `BidirIt` is a *concept* of a [*bidirectional iterator*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator) type. Both standard library containers' iterators and raw pointers satisfy it, that's why it works.

Comment: Thanks @Bartek Banachewicz !
Yeah, this is esactly what I was looking for. But I did not understand how it works. Could you please provide me the link where I can learn that?

Comment: @user2916888 The two links I've posted (especially the 2nd one) should make it clear. If they don't, you'll probably need to get back to your book and re-read the chapter about standard containers and iterators.

Comment: @user2916888 besides what's already posted in here, you could also take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap#Possible_implementation. I believe that'd make things clear enough.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a funny fact:

Your code works with arrays even if you remove `*` from the parameters.

```
template<typename T> void reversearr(T begin, T end) {
```

Why?

Because in your original code, `T` is `int`, and `T*` of the function parameters is `int*`.
In my modified code, `T` is `int*`, and the function parameters are *still* `int*`.

And this "version" works with iterators - the syntax and semantics of iterators are chosen so you can write generic functions that work equally well with pointers or iterators.

Comment: Thanks molbdnilo. Yes, I realised it after @wangfx gave the same answer :)